# Problem in Visualizing the different color channels of an RGB image

Tags: python, computer-vision

I needed a help in this.I am a newbie in computer vision. I am trying to visualize the different color channels of an RGB image in python using `PyCharm`. But whenever I run the code I get the original image as the only output, the rest of the color channel goes missing. Here is the code snippet.

```
import cv2 

image = cv2.imread('grasses.jpeg') 

B, G, R = cv2.split(image) 

cv2.imshow("original", image) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.imshow("blue", B) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.imshow("Green", G) 

cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.imshow("red", R)

cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you really searched exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You press any key in keyboard?

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```